# Mixture data for pair-copula model

Tags: data-request, finance

I am a PhD student and would like to get a mixture real data that may exhibit upper and lower tails dependencies along with other dependencies structure. I am working on a pair-copula models.

These models mean that, if we have a multivariate data, then we can build an acyclic tree where only two variables are modelled at a time. These models help to model non-normal dependence structures.

I would like to have a multivariate data that exhibit mixture dependencies between each variables and hope these dependencies including tail dependencies. Most of this data can be financial.

Answer (score 0):

According to the wikipedia article [Tail Dependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_dependence):

> stock returns ... commonly exhibit tail dependence.

To look at generic stock data, one of the easiest sources of historic data is [Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/search). Here's a [blog post](https://blog.quandl.com/stock-market-data-ultimate-guide-part-1) (June 2017) from them giving an overview.

Quandl has some paid products, but many/most data sources are free. They also have an [API](https://www.quandl.com/tools/api). [Blog about API](https://blog.quandl.com/getting-started-with-the-quandl-api), and example of simple CSV export:

```
https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/AAPL.csv
```

and endpoints for many codes.